# Laravel: Where does report() store the error messages?

Tags: laravel

According to the Laravel handling error documentation I've put this code snippet in one of my functions:

```
try {
    // Send an email...
} catch (Throwable $e) {
    report($e);
 
    return false;
}
```

Now I want to check out the error messages but I have no idea where they are stored.
I've tried both `storage/logs/laravel.log` and `var/log/apache2/error.log` but I found nothing.

Where does report() store the error message ?

Comment: just tested on my machine and it is going in `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your `config/logging.php`.

By default it should be the `stack` channel.
If your channel is set up to `daily` it willl create a file per day (e.g: `laravel-2022-05-16.log`
Otherwise you can leave the `single` channel it will put everything in `storage/logs/laravel.log`